# MySQL: Select multiple columns and total sum in one column

Tags: php, mysql, select, query-optimization

I've a table like:

```
-----------+------|
product_id |price |
-----------+------|
  1        + 5    |
-----------+------|
  2        + 15   |
-----------+------|
  3        + 25   |
-----------+------|
```

I need the output like:

```
-----------+------|
product_id |sum   |
-----------+------|
  1        + 45   |
-----------+------|
  2        + 45   |
-----------+------|
  3        + 45   |
-----------+------|
```

My current query:

```
 SELECT  product_id, (SELECT SUM(price) FROM tableName) `sum` FROM  tableName.
```

Is it possible to do this without using 2 SELECT queries or GROUP_CONCAT ?
Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Note: I've thousands of rows in my table and more conditions (to include other table data) will be added to this query.

Comment: Show us what your query is right now and what you've tried to get the sum into your array.

Comment: Question updated. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Just use group by.

```
 SELECT 
product_id, (SELECT SUM(price) FROM tableName) `sum` 
FROM  
tableName 
group by .
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a query like this:

`SELECT *, sum(price) AS sum FROM table WHERE condition = value`

Comment: This will return only one row.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code

```
select product_id, (select sum(price) from PRODUCTS) as sum FROM products
```

Comment: Can you produce the same output without using 2 select queries?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT product_id , sum(price) AS sum FROM table WHERE condition = value
```

try not using sub query in select statement.

Comment: This will return only one row.